# Trying to make my Tikz image bigger

Tags: tikz-pgf

This is my code for the Tikz image. I want to make this bigger.
I tried adjusting the max width to 250 mm but didn't change the size.
Can someone help me>

```
\begin{figure}[H]
\caption{Caption}
\label{fg:figure1}
\begin{center}
\begin{adjustbox}{max width = 200mm}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
axis lines = left,
xlabel = x axis,
ylabel = y axis,
xmin=9, xmax=14,
ymin=35, ymax=77,
xtick={9.0, 9.5, 10.0, 10.5, 11.0, 11.5, 12.0, 12.5, 13.0, 13.5},
ytick={35, 40, 45, 50, 55, 60, 65, 70, 75},
legend pos=north west,
]
\addplot [
domain=9.5:13.3,
samples=50,
color=blue,
]
{4.0512*x+2.2379};
\addplot[
only marks,
color=blue,
mark=*,
error bars/.cd,
y dir=both, y explicit,
x dir=both, x explicit,
]
coordinates {
(11.6,47.1) +- (0,0)
(13.0,67.1) +- (0,0)
(12.0,70.1) +- (0,0)
(12.5,61.8) +- (0,0)
(12.0,65.7) +- (0,0)
(12.7,55.8) +- (0,0)
(13.0,58.2) +- (0,0)
(12.4,58) +- (0,0)
(12.5,62.8) +- (0,0)
(12.4,51.3) +- (0,0)
(12.2,51) +- (0,0)
(12.0,47.7) +- (0,0)
(11.7,49.2) +- (0,0)
(12.1,45.6) +- (0,0)
(12.2,56.3) +- (0,0)
(11.8,54.9) +- (0,0)
(12.3,49.7) +- (0,0)
(12.9,42.8) +- (0,0)
(13.3,50) +- (0,0)
(12.5,53.9) +- (0,0)
(11.4,43.2) +- (0,0)
(12.0,52.9) +- (0,0)
(11.5,47.1) +- (0,0)
(12.1,45.7) +- (0,0)
(11.4,42.8) +- (0,0)
(11.5,39.6) +- (0,0)
(11.1,43.9) +- (0,0)
(11.5,44.7) +- (0,0)
(12.1,39.3) +- (0,0)
(12.4,44.7) +- (0,0)
(12.0,50.8) +- (0,0)
(12.5,46.3) +- (0,0)
(11.5,49.7) +- (0,0)
(11.8,43.4) +- (0,0)
(11.2,53.1) +- (0,0)
(11.3,45.7) +- (0,0)
(11.0,38.6) +- (0,0)
(11.8,45.9) +- (0,0)
(11.4,58.3) +- (0,0)
(11.4,43.7) +- (0,0)
(10.9,45.1) +- (0,0)
(11.7,48.3) +- (0,0)
(11.2,45.5) +- (0,0)
(11.1,47) +- (0,0)
(11.3,51.3) +- (0,0)
(11.5,58.5) +- (0,0)
(9.5,48.4) +- (0,0)
};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{adjustbox}
\end{center}
\end{figure}
```

Comment: Try adding `\pgfplotsset{width=8in, height=5in}` before the first axis.  Or whatever sizes you want...